# Google BigQuery Error: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update an old table referencing a new table by doing comparisons (i.e. values that are changed).

My query is as follows:

```
UPDATE CogencyData.AUM
SET BeginBalanceBase = T1.BeginBalanceBase
FROM Cogency_Temp.AUM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CogencyData.AUM T2
ON T1.FundLongName = T2.FundLongName
AND T1.PeriodDate = T2.PeriodDate
WHERE COALESCE(T1.BeginBalanceBase, 0) <> COALESCE(T2.BeginBalanceBase);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row
```

I believe the code works fine in MySQL. How can I fix this?

Comment: Comment out your top 2 lines (`UPDATE`/`SET`) and replace with `SELECT T1.BeginBalanceBase as T1BBB, T2.BeginBalanceBase as T2BBB`.  Do you get any results?

Comment: @rtenha Yes. I get two values as the result - perhaps that is why the query is confused? How can I effectively update those two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the same error:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.users AS (
   SELECT "1" id, 3 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "2", 2 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "3", 4 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "4", 5 total
)
;

UPDATE temp.users T0
SET total = T1.total + T2.total
FROM temp.users T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp.users T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE 1>0
```

This query fixes the error:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.users AS (
   SELECT "1" id, 3 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "2", 2 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "3", 4 total
   UNION ALL SELECT "4", 5 total
)
;

UPDATE temp.users T0
SET total = T1.total + T2.total
FROM temp.users T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp.users T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE 1>0
AND T0.id = T1.id
```

What's the trick: The last `WHERE` clause `T0.id = T1.id` ensures that each row in the table being updated only gets one update.